# startForegroundService() is throwing IllegalStateException in Oreo on app BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, service, illegalstateexception, foreground-service

The application I am having (in Android O) will start a service after device reboot. Once the device is rebooted, in the onReceive() method of the broadcast receiver it is calling the service as startForegroundService() for Android OS 8 and above.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(intent);
} else {
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

Inside the service class it is starting the notification from the onStartCommand() method.

But still it is throwing the IllegalStateException. Did someone faced similar issues in Android OS 8 and above?

Comment: `IllegalStateException` with which message?

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `startForeground()` from the started service, it's in the docs:

> Once the service has been created, the service must call its startForeground() method within five seconds.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#StartingAService)

So for example you need to do this from your `Service` class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_01";
        String CHANNEL_NAME = "Channel Name";

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setSound(null, null);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        Builder notification = new Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID).setSound(null).setVibrate(new long[]{0});
        notification.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);

        startForeground(1, notification.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: i try this solution but some time is cash .

Answer (score 1):

> The system allows apps to call Context.**startForegroundService**() even while the app is in the background. However, the app must call that service's **startForeground**() method within five seconds after the service is created.

Write your service's onCreate like below.

```
@Override
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("")
                .setContentText("").build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
    }
 }
```

So that startForeground() can be called within 5 seconds of starting the service.