# Foreground Service doesn't run in Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

I have a foreground service that runs on my phone(Android 7.0) but it doesn't run on a friends phone(Android 8.0).I also test it on android studio emulators and i have the same problem on version 8.0.I've implemented the **if-else check** to see if it's Android 8.0 so i can call **startForegroundService()** and still nothing.

Here is how i call it:

```
 //Start foreground service
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyForeGroundService.class);
    intent.setAction(MyForeGroundService.ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForegroundService(intent);
    }else{
        startService(intent);
    }
```

And here is my foreground service:

```
public class MyForeGroundService extends Service implements LocationListener {

public MyForeGroundService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    wakeLock();
}

@SuppressLint("InvalidWakeLockTag")
public void wakeLock() {
    pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    assert pm != null;
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "partialwl");
    wl.acquire();
}

public  void stopWakeLock() {
    wl.release();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        switch (action) {
            case ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE:
                wakeLock();
                startForegroundService();
                break;
            case ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE:
                stopWakeLock();
                stopForegroundService();
                break;
            case ACTION_PLAY:
                Intent openMap= new Intent(this,Map.class);
                startActivity(openMap);
                break;
            case ACTION_PAUSE:
                break;
        }
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

/* Used to build and start foreground service. */
private void startForegroundService() {
    Log.d(TAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE, "Start foreground service.");

    // Create notification default intent.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Map.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    // Create notification builder.
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    //Go back to Map activity if user press at the notification
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle("gEKOning...")
            .setContentText("Tap to open gEKOn app");


    builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Bitmap largeIconBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setLargeIcon(largeIconBitmap);
    // Make the notification max priority.
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    // Make head-up notification.
    builder.setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true);


    // Build the notification.
    Notification notification = builder.build();

    // Start foreground service.
    startForeground(1, notification);
}
private void stopForegroundService() {
    Log.d(TAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE, "Stop foreground service.");

    // Stop foreground service and remove the notification.
    stopForeground(true);

    // Stop the foreground service.
    stopSelf();
}
```

Comment: This answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53081689/4255978

Comment: @HedeH what is this Channel name?Where do i know what is the name?

Comment: It doesn't matter, It's just for Android to manage the notifications. You can read about notification channels if you want to lear more: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Comment: @HedeH Thank you very much!Works fine!Just one more question.I want to implement my own title,text and image and i want also when the user presses on the notification to open the app.Now if the user presses the app it opens settings.Any ideas?

Comment: It opens settings because you didn't specify a `PendingIntent`, `title` etc.. So the system is creating the notification for you. You need to add stuff to the `Notification.Builder`. Look here: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

Comment: @HedeH Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: It's actually running. You just need to create a Notification channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a notification channel. Something like this will do.

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
// Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
// the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
    String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
    channel.setDescription(description);
    // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
    // or other notification behaviors after this
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}}
```

Comment: Some people including me get this confusion that the FCM is not working when they test the Notification in the emulator. I was testing in Nexus 5 virtual device. I did not realize that it was running on Android O. Good call